# Whats the minimum iOS version which supports OpenGL ES2.0?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am not sure if the question even makes sense. I am writing an iPhone game which uses Opengl ES 2.0. I know that OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported on 3gs and higher. Is there a minimum requirement for iOS version too, like the device needs to have iOS 3.1.3 or higher? Or does it solely depend on the hardware?

Thanks!
-shireesh

p.s. I tried to search on the net but havent found much, perhaps I am not using the right keywords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [EAGLContext ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007624-CH3-SW2), the ES2 API has been available since 3.0. Any device that CAN run ES2 will already be running that OS, (hopefully 4.0)

Comment: Yes, OpenGL ES 2.0 was first supported in hardware with the iPhone 3G S, which ran 3.0 when it came out.